# DCDC booster oscillation because of small drops of input voltage

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, dc-dc-converter, oscillation, compensation

I'm stuck with this DCDC booster design that shows a bad oscillation output when a little voltage drop is present at the input.

I have already tried to change the inductance to 4.7uH (actually, the oscillation shown in the image below is with the L=  4.7uH). I have also tried to change the output capacitors to some with better ESR, which has some impact in the oscillation, but doesn't remove it.

These are the requirements of the booster:

- VIN-> 3.3V to 4.1V
- VOUT-> 5V to 13V. Adjustable via DAC output (from a CPU).
- IOUT-> 200mA average. Some peaks at startup the system of 1A (200ms.)

My voltage source input is a Li-ion battery with some series resistance.  The ripple current demanded by the inductor is the origin of the voltage drop at the input, so I cannot get rid of the voltage drop in first instance. I have to live with that.

[image: Green= input; Yellow= Output]

[image: Booster DCDC converter (L has been changed to 4.7uH)]

Added the layout:
[image]
[image: silk top]
[image: top layout]
[image: inner layer 1]
[image: inner layer 2]

Comment: Can you add more capacitance at the input?

Comment: Try R41=22k, C21=4.7n

Comment: That doesn't look like oscillation on the output.  It looks rather more like the output isn't properly regulating.

Comment: Yes, it is most likely that the output oscillation is causing input current spikes and resultant noise.

Comment: @JohnD I added a bulk capacitor to minimize the effect (1,000 uF). It wouldn't be feasible to use that but I did it anyway to get an idea of the importance of this. No big change. The waveform in the post is with the 1,000 uF already in place. I must say also that an electrolytic capacitor has also a good deal of ESR, so probably I will revisit the idea.

Comment: @JRE Yes, you guys are right. I probably should define it as an instability of the dcdc converter instead of oscillation. My feeling is that the feedback is "over-reacting", as if Kp (in terms of control jargon) is too large.

Comment: @JonathanS. Thanks for the tip, I'll try it out and let you know. Why did you decide those values? anything I could learn from that?

Comment: Whats the value of the upper feedback resistor? There is no label for it in the schematic. Whats the voltage on FB_DAC and what is the output voltage supposed to be?

Comment: You might try adding a small feedforward capacitor across the upper divider resistor.  Without some analysis a wild guess would be to try 20-40 pF.  It doesn't look like a small-signal instability, but it might help anyway.  I don't see anything wrong with the schematic at first glance, so you might have a layout issue.

Comment: I'd suggest calculating a pair of feedback resistors for a fixed voltage.  Set it up for that fixed voltage and remove the DAC connection and see it if can put out a stable, fixed voltage.

Comment: Post your layout

Comment: @LarsHankeln Thanks for the question, you are right, for some reason the value and reference are gone. R43 = 30k

Comment: @VoltageSpike Done, please see the edited posting with the layout now added. I followed Texas Instruments recommendations closely for that.

Answer (score 0):

Your waveforms are consistent with a too-low duty cycle.  Since this is running in PWM mode, most controllers have a minimum pulsewidth.  When the switch turns "on" you will start to charge your inductor, and the inductor's current will increase.  In your case, the inductor current may become too high; it's enough to pull down your battery voltage even though they have a low internal resistance.  The energy stored in the inductor is then dumped into your load.  If the minimum pulsewidth is too wide, the inductor is over-charged and the output voltage rapidly increases to a too-high value.  Then, the load resistor discharges the capacitors until the voltage drops to a point where the entire process is repeated.  PWM cycles are skipped during this time as the controller "waits" for the voltage to get back to the regulation area.

You should aim for an inductor/load/switching frequency combination that puts your duty cycle in the 25-40% range, but, as a minimum, make your minimum pulsewidth at the lightest expected load several times the minimum pulsewidth specified by the manufacturer, to avoid pulse skipping.